# How to retrieve an array of entities from the reques object?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, request, symfony-2.1, entities

I have an entity field type in my form, but then when I try to get the values from the controller I get an error.

This is my form builder

```
$builder
        ->add('recursos', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'SIGIConvocatoriasBundle:Recurso',
                'property' => 'nombre',
                'multiple' => true,
                'mapped' => false
                ))
        ->add('requisitos', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'SIGIConvocatoriasBundle:Requisito',
                'property' => 'nombre',
                'multiple' => true,
                'mapped' => false
                ))
    ;
```

and this is my controller

```
$entity  = new Convocatoria();
$form = $this->createForm(new ConvocatoriaType(), $entity);
$form->bind($request);
$recursos = $request->request->get('recursos');
foreach ($recursos as $recurso)
{
    //Do something ...
}
```

But I get an error here

```
Invalid argument in foreach ...
```

Like if the `$recursos` variable is empty or something, and I get a `'recursos' => null` in the symfony exception.
I'd really appreciate some help here :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request itself contains raw data (scalars).
When you `bind` the request to the form, it will transform this raw data to normalized data.
The array of ids will be transformed to an array of entities, and then be passed to `$entity->setRecursos(); // or each one to $entity->addRecurso();`

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ConvocatoriaType(), $entity)
$form->bind($request);

$formData = $request->request->get($form->getName());
$formData['recursos']; // should be an array of ids

$entity->getRecursos(); // array of entities
```

Comment: Yes, The only possible way I found was to use the `$form['recursos']`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
             $entity  = new Convocatoria();
             $form = $this->createForm(new ConvocatoriaType(), $entity);
             $form->bind($request);

              foreach ($entity->getRecursos() as $recurse) {
                    //do something
                }

             $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($entity);
                $em->flush();
```

Comment: The problem is that the attribute is not mapped, so it's ignored by the `$form->bind($request)` thus I can't use the `$entity->getRecursos` ... xD

Comment: When mapping forms to objects, all fields are mapped. Any fields on the form that do not exist on the mapped object will result in an exception.

Comment: If you need extra fields in the form which does not exist in your entity then add ->add('extraField', null, array('property_path' => false))

Comment: as of symfony 2.0.9 `property_path` was replaced by `mapped` as you can see in my form builder. Thanks for your help.